# Публичные вложенные классы - плохая практика?

Tags: c#, .net

Вот смотрю я на некоторые классы стандартных библиотек и думаю, а почему их не сделали вложенными и публичными, чтобы подчеркнуть их "ареал".

Например, есть `DataTable` и `DataRow`. `DataRow` нигде, вроде, не используется вне контекста `DataTable` и более того, отсутствует конструктор => создание возможно только через фабричный метод. Или `DataColumn`...

Так почему бы не подчеркнуть принадлежность вынеся классы во внутрь `DataTable`?

И вообще, вроде, не особо я часто встречал(по моему никогда), что бы использовали это возможность.

Почему так?

Comment: Просто если вдруг понадобится этот класс в другом контексте, он не сможет быть вызван без определения внешнего класса где он определен. Внутренние классы есть смысл использовать, если они будут использовать элементы родителя, 
чтобы не передавать лишнего в конструкторах,а так лучше и практичнее создавать внешний класс.

Comment: @And Разве? По моему внешний класс по отношению к внутреннему является чем-то вроде неймспейса.

Comment: Ну, это что-то из разряда - так принято. Я не помню, чтобы где-то микрософт строго рекомендовал писать как-то конкретно. Но вообще для подчеркивания "ареала" и так существуют пространства имён, поэтому хранить публичные классы внутри другого класса как-то бессмысленно. Разве что это какое-то эстетическое удовольствие тебе доставит))

Comment: Вы имели ввиду вложенные (_nested_)? Внутренние - это `internal`.

Comment: @i-one да. Поправлю ща.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ну почему же, используется, но только для тех типов, которые не особо фигурируют напрямую в коде. Например, [`List<T>.Enumerator`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.enumerator?view=netcore-2.0), который используется только неявно кодом, генерируемым компилятором для foreach. Для обычных типов их использовать действительно не рекомендуется, на это даже есть специальное предупреждение анализаторов [CA1034](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1034-nested-types-should-not-be-visible). Причина банальна - это неудобно; при каждом использовании такого типа снаружи нужно приписывать имя содержащего типа, сократить используя using нельзя. Ну и с точки зрения архитектуры: вложенность это не просто область видимости, она позволяет вложенному классу работать с private-членами содержащего. Если это не нужно по логике взаимодействия этих классов, лучше не связываться с таким нарушением инкапсуляции.

Answer (score 7):

Класс в классе увеличивает размер файла. Если в файле более трёхсот строк, с ним уже не очень удобно работать. Если ваш класс становится слишком большим, это подсказывает, что, возможно, нарушен принцип *единственной ответственности* (single responsibility).

Поэтому классы в классах используют только тогда, когда вы передаёте важную информацию для программиста, который будет поддерживать и изменять ваш код. Если класс `Bar` находится в `Foo`, значит, он должен знать, как устроен `Foo`.

Пример: реализуем паттерн [Memento](http://cpp-reference.ru/patterns/behavioral-patterns/memento/):

> Клиент является "посыльным" за Memento, но только исходный объект может сохранять и извлекать информацию из Memento (Memento является "непрозрачным" для клиентов и других объектов).

Из описания паттерна мы понимаем, что класс `Originator` и класс `Memento` должны знать друг о друге гораздо больше, чем остальные классы. Именно для подчёркивания этого факта нужно разместить один внутри другого. Я бы размещал `Memento` внутри `Originator` и вынес бы в него сохранение и восстановление состояния, чтобы оставить в `Originator` только его основную ответственность.

Поскольку в подавляющем большинстве случаев мы всё-таки хотим скрыть детали реализации, мы не используем этот приём слишком часто.

Comment: Касательно размера файла. В C# можно сделать класс `partial` и разнести его код по нескольким файлам.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, да. Мы именно так выносим вложенные классы у себя. Это решение привносит дополнительную сложность. Если класс лезет к другому классу, поля которого описаны в соседнем файле, вы начинаете скакать по проекту. Или, например, можете забывать сериализовать поле в классе `Memento`, добавив его в `Originator`.